# Replace data "mysql data" from "mysql backup" and lose all databases in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, apache

I cannot start mysql because port 80 was occupied by httpd.exe. I watched a tutorial on this community and followed suit. That is move all the folders in (C:\xampp\mysql\backup) to (C:\xampp\mysql\data) and REPLACE. It was successful. BUT, when I access phpmyadmin, i can't open any tablle in any database. And I get this error message "#1932 - Table 'donationranking.members' doesn't exist in engine". Can I recover them? I have not backed up data. Oh no, no no no no no no no...

Comment: MySQL does not run on port 80. Why did you overwrite your data from a backup to change the port? Why do you want to change the port to 80 anyway? What *exactly* did you do, which advice did you follow? And again, why? Why do you replace data without having a backup?

Comment: I guess I'm the type of person who will follow instructions like "delete the system32 folder to make the computer more stable"...